# Angular 5 and IE11 problems that requires shims for IE

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11

I am using Angular 5 and am attempting to run my application in IE11. I have  uncommented the necessary code within `.\my-app\src\polyfills.ts` but unfortunately am receiving the following error within my index.html file relating to this code:

```
<script>
  System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>

Error: 'System' is undefined
```

I have looked around and found the following Github issue with potential fix:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7144

Within this thread, it mentions that I need to include in my index.html file,  this:

**shims_for_IE.js**

Now, I am using Angular 5 but I am not sure where to locate this shims_for_IE.js file in order to place it within my `index.html` file.

How can I solve this `'System' is undefined` issue within IE11?

Comment: remove `not` keyword from line of `not IE 9-11` from browserlist file

Comment: @AbhayGawade Sorry, unsure where to locate this browserlist file inorder to remove the `not` keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Non CLI**

For Non CLI Project import `shim.min.js` in `index.html`

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

**For CLI**

In your `polyfills.ts` uncomment these line

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10, IE11, and Chrome <55 requires all of the following polyfills.    

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Add this meta tag in `index.html` file as mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```